# Get values of all rows in one column

Tags: vb.net

I have a Dataset
There are five columns in the set. I need to get the value in each row in one single column - for example: The value of each row in Column A.

How would I do this?

**UPDATE:**
Im sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm new to DB style programming, but I pick up on examples fast for learning.

I have a Dataset populated with 5 columns and an unknown number of records (rows) past row 4.
I need to populate a menu with everything past row 4 in the second (name) column.

DB Example:

id|name|etc|etc|etc

1 |this|etc|etc|etc
and on...

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Show some sample data and desired output. Include code you have tried so far, if possible.

Comment: Updated original question

Comment: still not so clear..

Comment: What can I add that will make it clearer to help? Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Let `dt` be your `Datatable` having columns `id` and `name` and you are going to select all records of column `name` then the following code will help you:

```
 Dim dt As New DataTable
 dt.Columns.Add("id")
 dt.Columns.Add("name")
 'populating datatable
 For i As Integer = 0 To 10
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
    dr("id") = i.ToString
    dr("name") = "a" & i.ToString
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
 Next
 ' result
 Dim selectedCols = New DataView(dt).ToTable(False, "name")
```